# ggplot color gradient does not change

Tags: ggplot2, colors, gradient, raster

I have a strange problem, which I did never face before. I crated a raster with the krige function and want to apply another color for the predicted values of the Raster.
I used ggplot and the scale_color_viridis option, it worked. However, any other method I try to apply (fill_brewer, color_brewer, fill_destiller, fill_gradientn, etc.) do not produce the colors I want. If I choose one of these options, the values are always displayed in the basic color gradient from black to blue. I cannot even invert the gradient with direction = -1. Again - it works for the viridis options. But the color options there are limited and I cannot find any reason, why ggplot only works with viridis for me. Can you find anything in the code? I already tried to convert the data into df, tibble, sf etc, nothing changes the result.

Thanks in advance :)

Here is the "working code"

```
gplot(
  data = KrigMap1, 
  mapping = aes(x = coords.x1, y = coords.x2, color = var1.pred)) +
  geom_point(size = 4, shape = 15) +
  scale_color_viridis(option = "C") +
  theme_classic() +
  xlab("X-coordinate") +
  ylab("Y-coordinate")
```

Comment: do you still have the problem? Could you please start a fresh R session and check if this problem occurs also with a very basic plot, such as `ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Petal.Length)) + geom_point()`?

Comment: the brewer scales are discrete, so it doesn't surprise me that it doesn't work with your plot. Any "fill" scale will also not work, because you need to scale to the color aesthetic.